# Android Honeycomb Stock Email Font

Tags: email, fonts

I'm using the stock email on Android 3.1 (ASUS Transformer) and I've configured my corporate email.

I need to know if it's possible to change the font used when creating or replying to emails. The font used, whilst nice enough, is a little too large.

Whats worse is when I view those sent emails in Windows 7/Outlook 2010, it gets rendered as Times New Roman.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the stock e-mail app sends mail in plain text only -- not HTML. Thus whatever client receives the message will render it in a default font for plain-text messages. For Outlook, that's apparently Times New Roman. (Courier New is another possibility.)

So your question might actually be "Can I send HTML e-mail from the stock Android app?"

Comment: Yes.. This is the answer.